# Is it ok to reuse the datetime object by setting timestamp?

Tags: php, datetime, object

I'm setting the timestamp to a different date/time and reusing the datetime object in my code. Reading around suggests it's better to create a new object each time instead. What's the best practice?

It seems to work fine, I'm not seeing any issues.

```
// common values
$timezone = "Australia/Melbourne";
$datetime1 = "2019-06-15 14:13:12+0000";
$datetime2 = "2019-06-10 11:12:13+0000";

$tz  = new DateTimeZone($timezone);
$dt = new DateTime();
$dt->setTimezone($tz);

// then I set a timestamp
$dt->setTimestamp(strtotime($datetime1));
$datetime = $dt->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
echo $datetime; // 2019-06-16 00:13:12

$dt->setTimestamp(strtotime($datetime2));
$datetime = $dt->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
echo $datetime; // 2019-06-10 21:12:13
```

It all works as expected but is it the right way to do this and are there things I need to watch out for?

Comment: Why they suggest to do a copy of the object?

Comment: Reading around earlier on SO all the answers suggest that creating a new object is cheap so it's best to do that. I couldn't find anywhere that recommended doing it the way I am and just wondering if it's wrong.

Comment: if the only reason is the "cheaping", it seems your practice is ok

Comment: The only valid reason I can think of if when you have multiple references to the same object. Then you might get unintended behavior.

Comment: Ok yep, in this particular case I use it for displaying records for a logged in user and set the time of the record according to their particular timezone. So the object is created once at the start of the script and then I use settimestamp in the loop that is displaying the records. There can be hundreds (or more) records and it didn't seem logical to create a new datetime object each time.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following use case:

```
$start = new DateTime('2019-07-09 13:00:00');
$end = $start->modify('+3 hours');

var_dump($start);
var_dump($end);
```

The result would be the following:

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2019-07-09 16:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(16) "America/New_York"
}
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2019-07-09 16:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(16) "America/New_York"
}
```

As you can see you can easily fall into a situation when you expect to have 2 variables having different dates but you end up in having the same object set to those 2 variables.

Being passed by reference, no matter which variable you modify at a later point, both variables will always hold the same `DateTime` object.

There are at least 3 possible ways to avoid this kind of situations:

1. **Create separate objects when setting the variables**

   ```
   $start = new DateTime('2019-07-09 13:00:00');
   $end = new DateTime('2019-07-09 16:00:00');

   object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
     ["date"]=>
     string(26) "2019-07-09 13:00:00.000000"
     ["timezone_type"]=>
     int(3)
     ["timezone"]=>
     string(16) "America/New_York"
   }
   object(DateTime)#2 (3) {
     ["date"]=>
     string(26) "2019-07-09 16:00:00.000000"
     ["timezone_type"]=>
     int(3)
     ["timezone"]=>
     string(16) "America/New_York"
   }
   ```
2. **Clone the object when you assign to the second variable**

   ```
   $start = new DateTime('2019-07-09 13:00:00');
   $end = (clone $start)->modify('+3 hours');

   object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
     ["date"]=>
     string(26) "2019-07-09 13:00:00.000000"
     ["timezone_type"]=>
     int(3)
     ["timezone"]=>
     string(16) "America/New_York"
   }
   object(DateTime)#2 (3) {
     ["date"]=>
     string(26) "2019-07-09 16:00:00.000000"
     ["timezone_type"]=>
     int(3)
     ["timezone"]=>
     string(16) "America/New_York"
   }
   ```
3. **Use `DateTimeImmutable`**

   ```
   $start = new DateTimeImmutable('2019-07-09 13:00:00');
   $end = $start->modify('+3 hours');

   object(DateTimeImmutable)#1 (3) {
     ["date"]=>
     string(26) "2019-07-09 13:00:00.000000"
     ["timezone_type"]=>
     int(3)
     ["timezone"]=>
     string(16) "America/New_York"
   }
   object(DateTimeImmutable)#2 (3) {
     ["date"]=>
     string(26) "2019-07-09 16:00:00.000000"
     ["timezone_type"]=>
     int(3)
     ["timezone"]=>
     string(16) "America/New_York"
   }
   ```

For an easy use-case, like yours, there is no need to worry about immutability because you don't need to reuse any date/time once you echo it, but in certain situations considering immutability is a must.

Comment: In your example though you are modifying $start and then applying the value of $start to $end. It will always make both of them the same value. In my case I create the object first and then use it to create new variables with settimestamp.

Comment: Of course, but that's a real scenario which could happen because of a developer lack of attention or any other reason. Somehow it explains your saying _Reading around suggests it's better to create a new object each time instead_

Comment: Ok yep, understood. Thanks for the input, much appreciated.